# (Unity3d) How to set horizontal layout group child's rect transform to stretch for fit to screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to set Horizontal layout group child's rect transform to stretch for fit to screen.[Horizontal layout group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JmL9.png) [layout group's child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmhlt.png)

I tried this options but these are not working [layout options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2rnD.png)